# Throwing away old history on git repo full of binaries

Tags: git

I've got a git repo with three years worth of PowerBuilder binary files.  The repo is pretty huge (just under 10GB), I assume due to the fact that git can only do so much for binary deltas.

I'd like to get this repo to a manageable size, and I'm willing to throw away a bunch of early history to do it.  I just can't figure out how to get git to do it.  I tried squashing commits with interactive rebase, but it comes up with a bunch of conflicts I don't want to deal with.

Is there a way to pick a commit, and just throw away everything before that?  I realize it will rewrite the SHA-1 for subsequent commits, which is no problem.

Comment: You definitely could compact all the prior commits using a rebase and squashes. I'm still thinking of an elegant/fast way to do that if you have so many commits.

Answer (score 1):

This is one (other) way:

```
git fast-export master~5..master | (cd ../newrepo.git && git init . && git fast-import && git checkout)
```

The above example will take commits in range `master~5..master` and create new repo out of that. You can use the same repo too, but the above will be safer.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebase the whole show down into a single commit.

Something like

```
git rebase -i [some early commit]
```

and then using visual block mode in vim to squash nearly all of them would be easiest, followed by an `fsck` and `gc` run.

Alternately, you can use `git filter-branch` to remove the commits from the tree entirely.